# how to input data to graphite server

Tags: linux, server, echo, graphite

I am using debian 8.0, and graphite installation is finished. I am testing a device, and I am trying to upload the device result data to the #graphite server. So far I have no problem creating file on graphite serve, but I could not upload any data.

The device telnet is connecting, but no data can be collected, would you point out where did I do wrong?

```
While True:    
    echo -en "0/0 pt_stream [0] ?'\r\n"  >&3
    read  <&3
   for i in `cat ${3} | tr '.' '\n'` ; do
       str=${str},${i}
       let n=$n+1
       var=`echo "var${n}"`
       echo $var is ... ${i}
   done
   echo "local.xena_sample.streams.stream0.bpstx $(val* date +%s)" | nc localhost 2003
done
```

Comment: can you post what you trying to send? remove pipe and nc and update question

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the echo statement to:

```
echo "local.xena_sample.streams.stream0.bpstx $val $(date +%s)" | nc localhost 2003
```